# Does concentration require line of sight to the spell effect being maintained?

Tags: dnd-5e, concentration

Does concentration on a spell require line of sight to the area of the spell, or can the caster move into cover and continue concentrating?  For example, a caster steps out of a doorway, casts Hypnotic Pattern, incapacitating 10 of 15 orcs, then ducks back through the doorway, closing the door, and continues to concentrate.  His allies now fight the orcs and the caster need not worry about the 5 unaffected orcs attacking him and forcing him to make concentration checks.

Taking things to a ridiculous extreme, could the caster cast the spell and then Teleport to the nearest inn and have a few drinks while continuing to concentrate on the spell from miles away?

Comment: Oops  Added the dnd-5e tag.